# How to run sql script in an anonymous block?

Tags: sql, bash, plsql

Is it possible to run an sql script in an anonymous block?

I would like to be able to conditionally run an sql script.

```
#!/bin/bash
.
.
.
`sqlplus -S /nolog > log3 << EOFSQL
connect ${userName}/${userPassword}@${urlDataBase};
set serveroutput on
set pagesize 0
set feedback off
set verify off
set heading off
set wrap off
set linesize 150
DECLARE
lv_error VARCHAR2(100):='';
BEGIN
SELECT TRIM(STATUS) INTO lv_error FROM tab1
WHERE ...

IF lv_error NOT LIKE 'ERROR%' THEN
START $(pwd)/script.sql;
/

END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: You mean from a shell script?

Comment: An anonymous block is written in the bash script that should run the sql script.

Comment: No, PL/SQL running on the database server cannot call client applications.

Comment: Hi, what are you trying to do inside the anonymous block? Are you trying to insert/update/delete something? or displaying something on console?

Comment: This script.sql is created dynamically by the dbms_output.put_line (x) command, depending on the data.
The script consists of another anonymous block that starts the procedure but I don't want to run if errors occur.

Answer (score 1):

In your case it is better to write a PL/SQL procedure and invoke it from the shell script.  That way, it is easier to conditionally call the second sql function/procedure.

Or, if you want to keep the logic in shell script, spool the output of the first SQL and then read it and call the second sql script.

Something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
.
.
.
sqlplus -S /nolog > log3 << EOFSQL
connect ${userName}/${userPassword}@${urlDataBase};
spool spool_out.txt
set linesize 150
DECLARE
lv_error VARCHAR2(100):='';
BEGIN
SELECT TRIM(STATUS) FROM tab1
WHERE ...

END;
/

EOFSQL


errorPresent=`cat spool_out.txt|grep "ERROR"`
if [ ! -z $errorPresent ]
the
    #Call $(pwd)/script.sql;
fi
```

Comment: Ok, this is a solution but I would not like to create a procedure
What do you think about it? 
errorPresent=`cat spool_out.txt|grep "ERROR"`
if [ -z errorPresent ]
the
   echo exit | sqlplus ${userName}/${userPassword}@${urlDataBase} @$(pwd)skrypt.sql 
fi